# Nonzero expectation value of boson creation operator in ground state of a Bose-Einstein condensate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization, bose-einstein-condensate

I was following along with these [notes](https://www.physics.upenn.edu/%7Ekane/pedagogical/boulderlec12.pdf), and just above equation (32) on page 3, the author makes the claim that, "for a Bose condensate, the ground state boson creation operator acquires a finite expectation value, $\langle b^\dagger \rangle = \sqrt{n} e^{i\phi}$". How can one arrive at this conclusion? Naively, it seems to me that the expectation value for any isolated creation or annihilation operator should be zero because
$$ \langle n | b^\dagger | n\rangle \propto  \langle n | n+1\rangle = 0$$
Thanks for the help!

Comment: check this out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state

Comment: You are right: for any vector of a Hilbert space of $N$ particles, this expectation value is zero. If you want a non-zero expectation value, you have to go to Fock spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since we are considering BEC, a ground state has a macroscopic occupation. It means that we can replace the field operators $a_{0}$ and $a^{\dagger}_{0}$ into c-numbers. Hence the ground state boson creation operator acquires a finite expectation value.